# Default system language issue

Tags: language-support, system-language

My default language is Polish. Sometimes when system loads, when I try to search something in web browser using polish letters (ąężźśćółń) I activate keyboard shortcuts (like normally ALT+A should give ą but it does something else, for ex. selects all text in site). If I change language to English and to Polish again (using language button [Pl] in this image [image: language button]) everything works correctly. Browser is just an example, in Steam chat I have similar problem until I change to EN and reselect PL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved problem by adding `setxkbmap -layout pl` to my `~/.profile` file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (some of) your custom keyboard shortcuts conflict with shortcuts which are already 'taken' by your system. Try changing your custom keyboard shortcuts so they are unique.